# Search for longest prefix

Tags: javascript, algorithm, typescript

Let's assume, it have an array of strings `D`. Given a string `Q`, I want to find the string in `D` that has the longest common prefix with `Q`.

I don't want a complicated data structure, but it still should be faster than just a linear scan.

Is there a solution to sort `D` in a clever way and just do a single binary search?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Clarification: Of course, if done only once, a single scan is faster than sorting. However, I need to do many such look ups on a fixed `D`, so this is why I am looking for a precomputed data structure.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me, on average even fastest sorting *O (n log n)* is slower than linear search *O (n)*.

Comment: It has to be done many times, so that's why I am looking for a precomputed data structure.

Comment: _"Is there a solution"_ what have you tried? It's not fun completing other peoples homework...

Comment: Couldn't you store your array of strings in a tree structure. then, for Q you would just walk the tree by character and find all common prefix strings as such? Or, sort D and then search on a sorted list instead of a random list.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hacked together an implementation in Java (because I don't know how to typescript or javascript). The approach is translatable though, so I am hoping this may be helpful.

This is my thought process:

D is constant so we want to find a way to find all words that have a common prefix. So, for this I implement:

- A tree-like structure which indexes the Strings based on their characters. Meaning the String `artur` will be stored in `a` -> `r` -> `t` -> `u` etc
- This puts indexing D in time complexity of O(n) where n is the length of the String.
- This puts searching for words sharing a common prefix to O(n) where n is the length of the prefix we are looking for

The approach has a few limitations so that I could test it faster: 
 * only allow lowercase letters
 * Store Strings in between to avoid traversal of the tree when finding a prefix.

So, for my code, I have these tests and also added some timing to see what happens:

```
public class CommonPrefixTree {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node treeRoot = new Node();

        index("Artur", treeRoot);
        index("ArturTestMe", treeRoot);
        index("Blop", treeRoot);
        index("Muha", treeRoot);
        index("ArtIsCool", treeRoot);

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            for(int j = 0; j < 20 ; j++) {
                b.append(chars[r.nextInt(chars.length)]);
            }
            strings.add(b.toString());
            index(b.toString(), treeRoot);
        }

        strings.add("art");
        strings.add("a");
        strings.add("artu");
        strings.add("arturt");
        strings.add("b");

        System.out.println(" ----- Tree search -----");
        find("art", treeRoot);
        find("a", treeRoot);
        find("artu", treeRoot);
        find("arturT", treeRoot);
        find("b", treeRoot);

        // The analog test for searching in a list

        System.out.println(" ----- List search -----");
        findInList("art", strings);
        findInList("a", strings);
        findInList("artu", strings);
        findInList("arturt", strings);
        findInList("b", strings);

    }

    static class Node {

        Node[] choices = new Node[26];
        Set<String> words = new HashSet();

        void add(String word) {
            words.add(word);
        }

        boolean contains(String word) {
            return words.contains(word);
        }

    }

    static List<String> findInList(String prefix, List<String> options) {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(String s : options) {
            if(s.startsWith(prefix)) res.add(s);
        }

        System.out.println("Search took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        return res;
    }

    static void index(final String toIndex, final Node root) {
        Node tmp = root;
        // indexing takes O(n)
        for(char c : toIndex.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            int val = (int) (c - 'a');
            tmp.add(toIndex);
            if(tmp.choices[val] == null) {
                tmp.choices[val] = new Node();
                tmp = tmp.choices[val];
            } else {
                tmp = tmp.choices[val];
                if(tmp.contains(toIndex)) return; // stop, we have seen the word before
            }
        }
    }

    static Set<String> find(String prefix, final Node root) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Node tmp = root;
        // step down the tree to all common prefixes, O(n) where prefix defines n
        for(char c : prefix.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            int val = (int) (c - 'a');
            if(tmp.choices[val] == null) {
                return Collections.emptySet();
            }
            else tmp = tmp.choices[val];
        }

        System.out.println("Search took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
        return tmp.words;
    }
}
```

**Results for Tree and raw list search**

Which will then result in these timings for the 5 searches for 100, 10000 and 500k strings:

100

```
----- Tree search -----
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
 ----- List search -----
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
```

10000

```
 ----- Tree search -----
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
 ----- List search -----
Search took: 2
Search took: 2
Search took: 2
Search took: 2
Search took: 2
```

500000

```
----- Tree search -----
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
Search took: 0
 ----- List search -----
Search took: 43
Search took: 27
Search took: 66
Search took: 25
Search took: 24
```

The main issue with this is creating the tree (and this might just be my hacky implementation of a tree or the way I waste memory doing it). So there is room for improvement. The tree creation does take quite a bit of time.

The experiment shows that lookup for common prefixes is stable in terms of time consumption using a tree for this.

Things to consider though may be:

- Sparse array for the data structure.
- Not storing the actual Strings but instead traversing the tree to find all common prefixes

Hope that helps - fun little exercise. Let me know if I stuffed it up completely :)

**Binary search on sorted input**

I also noticed you asked for a not-complicated datastructure, so I tried the following:

- Sort the input list of Strings
- Binary search for the first index that matches the prefix we look for
- collect prefixes left and right

This results to this code (again, sorry, it is Java but it should be translatable quite easily:)

```
static Set<String> getCommonPrefix(final String prefix, final List<String> input) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int index = Collections.binarySearch(input, prefix, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                // o2 being the prefix
                if(o1.startsWith(o2)) return 0;
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        });

        if(index < 0) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        Set<String> res = new HashSet<>();
        res.add(input.get(index));

        boolean keepSearching = true;
        int tmp = index - 1;
        while(keepSearching && tmp > 0) {
            if(input.get(tmp).startsWith(prefix)) {
                res.add(input.get(tmp));
            } else {
                keepSearching = false;
            }
            tmp--;
        }

        keepSearching = true;
        tmp = index + 1;
        while(keepSearching && tmp < input.size()) {
            if(input.get(tmp).startsWith(prefix)) {
                res.add(input.get(tmp));
            } else {
                keepSearching = false;
            }
            tmp++;
        }

        System.out.println("Search took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

        return res;
    }
```

This one has an interesting behaviour. The search would take `O(log n)`, where `n` is the input size of the array. Then the collection is linear `k` where `k` is the amount of common prefixes.

The interesting bit is that, as long as the prefix is rather large, this approach is very quick (comparable to the tree implementation), but once you look for very little prefixes, this becomes a bit slower as the amount of Strings to retrieve is rather big. The timings in detail are (for 5 million random Strings):

```
Search for 'art' took: 1
Found strings: 309
Search for 'artur2' took: 0
Found strings: 1
Search for 'asd' took: 0
Found strings: 265
Search for 'nnb' took: 1
Found strings: 276
Search for 'asda' took: 0
Found strings: 10
Search for 'c' took: 63
Found strings: 192331
```

I suppose, from a java-script point of view, if you have a build-in binary search, the last approach is probably the easiest and most straight forward one to choose from as building and maintaining a tree is a bit more involved + (for me) took a lot of time to index the Strings.

Comment: This seems like Java, but the questions is tagged 'javascript' and 'typescript'.

Comment: That is true. The idea can be translated quite easily though.

Answer (score 2):

Create a **tree** based on the characters in `D`:

Each `node` contains the `character` and a list of child `node`s.

E.g., if `D` is

```
 a
 ab
 ac
 ace
 d
```

then

- there are 2 top level nodes `a` and `d`
- `d` has no children
- `a` has 2 children - `b` and `c`
- `b` has no children
- `c` has 1 child - `e`
- `e` has no children

Lookup (and adding to the tree!) is basically walking the nodes until there are no matching children.

E.g., suppose `Q=af`. There is a top node containing `Q[0]=a`, but it has no children with `Q[1]=f`, so the longest prefix is `a`. All children of the `a` node represent strings in `D` which have the longest common prefix with `Q`, specifically, `a`, `ab`, `ac`, `ace`.

Both lookup and add operations are linear in string length, so creation of the structure takes `O(sum(len(x) for x in D))` time and lookup is `O(len(Q))`.

Comment: How do you get the original string from the tree then?

Comment: @Pavlo: what "original string"?

Comment: As in question: 'I want to find the string in D that has the longest common prefix with Q.'. So I imagine finding the prefix itself would be easy, but how about the whole string?

Comment: After you find the end node corresponding to the given prefix, *all* children of the node represent strings in `D` with this prefix.